# Split first name and last name of a person, stored as one field

Tags: sql, oracle10g

so I explained my situation :

I got a table, with old datas, containing some tutors.

It's identity is stored into one field.

Some samples :

```
Le Raie Jean
Martin Jean-Michel
Bernard-Dubois Jacques
```

All those data are on one field, while it should be more like this :

```
Name  |  FirstName
Le Raie | Jean
Martin | Jean-Michel
Bernard-Dubois | Jacques
Le Raie | Jean jacques
```

As you can see, a last name can be in two parts, some with a space, some with the `-`.

Same for the first name.

I must absolutly have the first name in the same field, so the rest into the firstname field.

And I don't see, what I can wrote to do it.

Because there can be no separator, a space or `-`, I don't see how to do it, without impact on the first name part.

I think using substring, but which rules should I use for it?

For now, I just have this Select statement :

```
SELECT decode(id_agent, null, 0, id_agent ), matricule, decode(id_agent, null, '0', '1' ),
decode(id_agent, null, record.identite, nom ), decode(id_agent, null, record.identite, prenom )
into v_nbNum, v_matricule, v_flagActif, v_nom, v_prenom
from t_agent;
```

I hope I have been clear. Did somebody got some ideas?

Comment: In general, you probably cannot split the data correctly in every case.  If you can't specify an algorithm, it's probably beyond the scope of what can reasonably be answered on SO.  There are entire products whose purpose is to take free-form text and parse it out into names and addresses based on a rather large number of rules (i.e. "Le" followed by another word is probably part of a last name).  You could try to enumerate a series of rules based on your data, that will likely help you get closer to correct but getting 100% correct output is very tough.

Comment: Agree with @JustinCave. Also, regardless of how much coding and time you put into your solution, you would have to go through each row manually to check the results.  In cases like this it might be faster to use data entry people to enter the data by hand or do the checking for you after you implemented your best solution.

Comment: @JustinCave Yeah, I was afraid of that. I can only do a thing that will work in the mostly cases, and not all.